# Unpack tar.bz2 file

Tags: tar

I'm trying to unpack in my Linux server (using Debian) the php 7.1.10 tar.bz2 archive, but it give me always the same error:

```
demo@localhost:/usr/local/src/php7-build$ tar xvjf php-7.1.10.tar.bz2
bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I tried also with jxf, xf, xjf, always the same error.

My version of tar is:

```
demo@localhost:~$ tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.27.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the file is undamaged? Run `sha256sum php-7.1.10.tar.bz2` and compare it to the published file[checksums at php.net](https://secure.php.net/downloads.php)

Comment: Check the file with `bzip2 -tv php-7.1.10.tar.bz2`. if it doesn't return `OK` then the file is corrupt or imcomplete

Comment: Yes, the file was corrupted. Thanks, I resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the files state to be sure it's not corrupted:

```
bzip2 -tv php-7.1.10.tar.bz2
```

It should return an `ok` if the file is ok, else you will need to redownload the file.

Comment: I'd skip such checks when a sha256 sum is available. bzip2-checking only checks if the file is a valid bz2-file - whilst a sha256 sum will check if it's *the* correct file.

Comment: I am aware of that but even `incorrect` files will still decompress

Comment: Exactly :) That's why I'd opt for the more secure option of checking the hash :)